# Pytube 15.0.0 cannot receive subtitles like it did before

Tags: python, pytube

I want to get subtitles from youtube video, using pytube library on python 3.11.3.

Code, for example:

```
import pytube
yt = pytube.YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvDOnqGbghU')
caption = yt.captions['a.en']
print(caption.generate_srt_captions())
```

I expected to get something like this:

> 1
> 00:00:10,200 --> 00:00:11,140
> K-pop!
>
> 2
> 00:00:13,400 --> 00:00:16,200
> That is so awkward to watch.

But get error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "...\application\1.py", line 3, in 
> caption = yt.captions['a.en']
> ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
> File "...\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\query.py", line 415, in **getitem**
> return self.lang_code_index[i]
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
> KeyError: 'a.en'

I think the problem is in "...venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\captions.py". I met there (in stackoverflow) the same issue (.../questions/68780808/), but solutions doesn't work in new version of pytube (15.0.0) or maybe problem in python 3.11.3

I think so, because this code...

```
en_caption = yt.captions
print(en_caption)
```

shows that dict "en_caption" is empty. I tried many videos, all of them give the same dict.

So how to solve this problem?

Comment: I think this is an open bug https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1674

Comment: I found ridiculous solution in bottom -https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1674. So when I add row print(len(yt.streams)) before "captions" it start working. Thanks, Cory Kramer @cory-a-kramer

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the `bypass_age_gate()`. With the new PyTube version it's mandatory to pass it.

```
import pytube
yt = pytube.YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvDOnqGbghU')
yt.bypass_age_gate()
caption = yt.captions['a.en']
print(caption.generate_srt_captions())
```

See also this thread: https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1674